# Minimize $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kb_jc_{ij}v_iw_j^2$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^kv_i=\sum_{j=1}^kw_j=1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $b_j,c_{ij}>0$ for $i,j\in\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}$. I want to solve the following problem in $v_i,w_j$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kb_jc_{ij}v_iw_j^2\\ \text{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^kv_i=\sum_{j=1}^kw_j=1\\ & v_i, w_j\ge0\end{array}\tag1$$

I am aware of the method of Lagrange multipliers, but I wasn't able to figure out how we might apply it here. So, what do we need to do?

**EDIT**: Ignoring the inequality constraints for a moment we could apply the Lagrange multiplier theorem as follows: Let $f(v,w):=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kb_jc_{ij}v_iw_j^2$ and $h(v,w):=\left(\sum_{i\in I}v_i-1,\sum_{i\in I}w_i-1\right)^T$ for $v,w\in\mathbb R^I$ and assume $(v,w)$ is a minimizer of $(1)$ without the nonnegativity constraint. Then there are $(\eta,\lambda)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^2$ with

1. $(\eta,\lambda)\ne0$
2. $\eta\in\{0,1\}$
3. $\nabla(f+\langle\lambda,h\rangle)(v,w)=0$

Now note that $$\nabla\langle\lambda,h\rangle(v,w)=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_2)^T\tag2$$ and $$\nabla f(v,w)=\left(\sum_{j\in I}b_jc_{1j}w_j^2,\ldots,\sum_{j\in I}b_jc_{|I|j}w_j^2,2w_1b_1\sum_{i\in I}c_{i1}v_i,\ldots,2w_{|I|}b_{|I|}\sum_{i\in I}c_{i{|I|}}v_i\right)^T.\tag3$$ If $\eta=0$, we would immediately obtain $\lambda=0$, which is impossible by 1. If $\eta=1$ we obtain a system of equations. How should we solve it?

Comment: Since you have a cubic objective, I don't think this is convex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I guess you're right. Do you know the solution using KKT?

Comment: That requires work! I think it would be wise to augment your question and provide context on the background and motivation for this question. Knowing the whole story, one can sometimes find a better question to ask. Asking good questions is hard.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This question is an attempt to find an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408572/47771) using pointwise minimization of the integrand. For fixed $x,y$, I've chosen $b_j:=1_{\left\{\:pq_j\:>\:0\:\right\}}(y)\frac1{q_j(y)}$, $c_{ij}:=\frac1{\sigma_{ij}(x,y)}$, $v_i:=w_ix)$ and $w_j:=w_j(y)$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Actually, the only inequality constraints we really need are $v_i,w_j\ge0$, since then $v_i,_j\le1$ is implicit by the equality constraints $\sum_iv_i=\sum_jw_j=1$. Can't we transform the problem by introducing auxiliary variables as we would do in linear progamming? If not, maybe we can solve the problem without the nonnegativity constraints and hope that there is a nonnegative solution.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Edit what? That we can drop the "$\le1$"?

Comment: $x_i^2 := v_i$ and $y_j^2 := w_j$ would get rid of the inequalities, but the problem would be transformed into minimizing a polynomial of degree $6$ over unit Euclidean spheres.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm not very experienced with such problems, but if you know an outline I might be able to work out the details by myself. Or maybe you're able to provide an answer for the case $k=2$ which might be a good starting point.

Comment: There is no need for experience. Just plug in $x_i^2$ wherever you see a $v_i$. You don't need the $b_j$ parameters, as they can be absorbed into $c_{ij}$.

Comment: This may be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0173

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Please take note of my edit.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oops, I've obviously intended to write "ignoring the nonnegativity constraint for a moment".

Comment: You still have to check whether a minimum is attained on the boundary. Hard combinatorial problems can be encoded as polynomial optimization problems. One should not be surprised if this is hard.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Should I try to find an analytical solution at all or do I need to apply numerical optimization?

Comment: Try to use KKT. You will obtain a system of polynomial equations that be solvable using symbolic solvers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you recommend a software/website to solve thre resulting system?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo BTW, do you think pointwise minimization of the integral in the other question (which led me to this question) is the correct approach at all?

Comment: If you use Python, you can try SymPy to solve systems of polynomial equations. I am not qualified to comment on the other question.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could you provide example code how we could solve the problem in the edit using Python? In the case $I=\{1,2\}$, for simplicity?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2034537/339790) of SymPy code. If you follow my suggestion and minimize a sextic polynomial over unit spheres, then you will need to compute all partial derivatives of the Lagrangian with respect to $x_i$ and $y_j$ and the two Lagrange multipliers and then find where they all vanish, which boils down to solving a system of polynomial equations over the reals. I assume you're not interested in complex-valued solutions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100309/discussion-between-0xbadf00d-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).